# How to design and document a non-REST web API?

Tags: rest, spring-boot, swagger, api-design

I need to design a Web API, which is not REST. It would work like this:

3rd party website (later called 'consumer') should make a POST call with JSON payload to my service. The call should be performed by a web browser. My service would process the request and show some UI, possibly leading the end user through a series of forms/pages and gathering inputs.
At the end my service will return a result and control to the 'consumer' by making a POST call to a callback URL specified by 'consumer'.

The technology used will be Spring Boot. My questions:

- is there some official name for this kind of API/integration?
- is there some smart (automated) way to document such API? Especially the JSON payload used as input and output. I tried using Swagger, but it does not seems to serve this use case very well. JSON Schema perhaps? I haven't used it before, at first sight it t looks a little abandoned and aimed more for validation.

Comment: Your second question is basically asking for a tool to generate documentation, which is considered off topic for Stack Overflow. Quoting [What topics can I ask about here?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic): *"Questions asking us to recommend or find a book, **tool**, software library, tutorial or other off-site resource are **off-topic** for Stack Overflow".

Answer (score 1):

For your first question, I suppose you can call it 'HTTP API', as you're leveraging the HTTP Protocol, without necessarily conforming to REST constraints. I base this on the following [reference](http://restcookbook.com/Miscellaneous/rest-and-http/).

With regards to your documentation, you can use something like [Slate](https://github.com/lord/slate), a markdown based API documentation generator.

Answer (score 0):

> My service would process the request and show some UI, possibly leading the end user through a series of forms/pages and gathering inputs.

If I understand this correctly, you are responding to the POST request 
with HTML ("show some UI", "forms/pages"). 
I wouldn't call this an API at all, and I probably wouldn't even use the word "service". I'd say that what you're designing is just a web application.

To turn it into an actual service, you need to separate it so that the UI parts are handled elsewhere, and have your service return only *data*. Since you're accepting JSON in the request payload, the most natural format for the response payload is also JSON.

If it is absolutely necessary for your service to redirect the user to a web page where they can provide additional information to continue whatever process the initial POST request is starting, then return a URL to that page. Let the URL include whatever query parameters are necessary for the web application UI to generate the forms.

(I'm assuming this is going to be dynamic in nature, because otherwise you would just specify this upfront and receive all the data in the request payload of the initial POST.)

An even cleaner approach would be to let the consumer handle all of the UI concerns, and only have your service tell the consumer what additional information it can/must supply in subsequent calls. This would give the consumer much more freedom, since it lets them use your API from any type of application (command-line, mobile app, web, etc.).

Comment: Well I guess it is is an API, because it is meant to be integrated with multiple external systems via standardized interface.. the  HTML UI would gather some inputs from the user, process them and finally return the result to the calling website

Comment: @TomaszSłota: An API should be easy to consume from any type of application, it should not return UI elements. The UI concerns (generating forms/pages) should be separated from the service. See suggested alternative approaches that I added to my response.